# PHPExcel taking format of empty cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

In an excel sheet where I previousely formatted the whole first colum as a date, I changed afterwards the format of the used cells to General (cells A1 to A11). So from cell A12, this first column still has the previous date format.
When I try to use the values of the first column (A1, A2, ..., A11) it identifies their format as a date, and gives a wrong result.

For example, this retruns a date format (d/mm/yyyy), which is not the case (see picture)

```
$sheet->getStyle('A3')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

Also the whole column has this format :

```
$sheet->getStyle('A')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

Is there a way to make sure the format of the cell itself is considered?
(when I indicated the format of this cells explicitely, the right format was used)

After some investigation, found that this problem occurs only for the .xlsx files (using reader PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007) and not for the .xls files (reader PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the whole row/col format:

```
$sheet->getStyle('A')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

Because you have changed only the format of A1 to A11, the rest are still with the old format. So setting format of the Whole Column/Row will fix this problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this (which works) :      
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:A20')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('General'); 
But there should be a general way to do this (I mean : to take the actual format of the cells and not imposing the 'General' format)

Comment: Well yes this was my solution, but it only sets the format of ALL the A* cells. Also setFormatCode gets styles from constants, it is good to use them.

Answer (score 0):

After some more invetigation found a possible cause in reader Excel2007.php.

There is a problem with the condition When setting the style (line 933):

```
if ($c["s"] && !$this->_readDataOnly) {
  $cell->setXfIndex(isset($styles[intval($c["s"])]) ? intval($c["s"]) : 0);
}
```

In case of General cell format, $c["s"] is not defined, and the _xfIndex of the cell is not set (not passing the if statement). This gives (I didn't found why) a problem with the stored _xfIndex of the cell.

When removing the $c["s"] condition, the right style is set.

```
if (/*$c["s"] &&*/ !$this->_readDataOnly) {
  $cell->setXfIndex(isset($styles[intval($c["s"])]) ? intval($c["s"]) : 0);
}
```

Hoping there are no hidden consequences.